# Outputting an Acts_As_Nested type Model (comments)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-templates, knockout.js

I have a Rails 3 `Acts_As_Nested` Model for Comments, which has the following fields:

- id
- parent_id
- lft
- rgt
- content

With Rails, it's easy to render a nested list of comments using things like `.parent` `.children` etc..

But now I want to use KnockoutJS to output the nested comments, via a jQuery Template. How do I output the nesting in jQuery Template + KnockoutJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted this on the KO forums, but added here too since the question is out here.

A nice way to do this would be to call a template recursively.  If your structure is nested, then you could pass the children each time to the template.  If your structure is flat, then you would need to filter the items that are passed to the template.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Xydth/

For the flat structure, it could look like:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'comment', foreach: viewModel.getChildren(0) }"></ul>

<script id="comment" type="text/html">
    <li>
       <span data-bind="text: content"></span>   
        <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'comment', foreach: viewModel.getChildren($data.id) }"></ul>
    </li>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function comment(id, parentId, content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.content = ko.observable(content);
}

var viewModel = {
    comments: ko.observableArray([
        new comment(1, 0, "one content"),
        new comment(2, 1, "two content"),
        new comment(3, 0, "three content"),
        new comment(4, 0, "four content"),
        new comment(5, 4, "five content"),
        new comment(6, 4, "six content"),
        new comment(7, 6, "secent content"),
        new comment(8, 0, "eight content")
        ]),
    getChildren: function(parentId) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.comments(), function(comment) {
            return comment.parentId == parentId;
        });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```